# SyntaxError: invalid syntax while installing simplejson 2.4 line 390 - python 2.4.3

Tags: python, installation, simplejson

i am trying to install simplejson2.4 on RedHat however getting:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid syntax encoder.py line 390
```

**Output:**

```
[~/tmp/simplejson-2.4.0]# python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running install_lib
byte-compiling /lib64/python2.4/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py to encoder.pyc
  File "/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 390
    if (not _bigint_as_string or
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Code**

```
...
388         elif isinstance(value, (int, long)):
389                         yield ((buf + str(value))
390                                if (not _bigint_as_string or
391                                    (-1 << 53) < value < (1 << 53))
392                                    else (buf + '"' + str(value) + '"'
...
```

please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simplejson requires python 2.5. Either upgrade your python (recommended), use an older version of simplejson or try ultrajson which, afair, supports python 2.4.

Comment: i tried installing 2.3.3 and still the same issue. do you know which simplejson version is supports python2.4? I checked the documentation and its was mentioned that it is backward compatible with 2.4

Comment: @m1k3y02 I would upgrade your Python version.

Comment: gcbirzan - i looked into the documentation again. you are right, python 2.4 is not supported since simplejson version 2.1 @CoffeRain - I am in the process :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is simplejson in below path: 
*/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/*